# If A is positive-definite what can we say about $x^t A y$ or $y^t A x$?

Tags: normed-spaces

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ positive definite matrix in $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^t A x}}{2}$, can I claim that $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You need to show that $x^t A y$ defines an inner product. Then the result follows.

The simplest way to show that this is true is in two steps

1. Since $A$ is positive definite, we can write $A=B^T B$.
2. Next use the change of basis $\hat x = B x$ and transfer the standard inner product from the new basis to original as shown next
   $$
   \hat x = B x, \hat y = B y, \hat x^t \hat y = x^T B^T B y = x^T A y$$

Thus 
$$<x,y> = x^T A y$$
is an inner product since
$$
<x,y> = <y,x>\\
<x,\alpha y + \beta z> = \alpha <x,y> + \beta <x,z>\\
<x,x> > 0, \forall x \ne 0, 
<0,0>=0
$$

Your problem reduces to
$$
\left|| x+y\right || \le \left|| x\right ||+\left|| y\right ||
$$
which is just triangle inequality.

Comment: I understand that x'Ay is an inner product. However, I'm still not clear on how to prove the claim above.

Comment: I understand that x'Ay is an inner product. However, I'm still not clear on how to prove the claim above: f(x+y) = sqrt(x'Ax +x'Ay+y'Ax+y'Ay)/2. How can I conclude that this is smaller than sqrt(x'Ax)/2 + sqrt(y'Ay)/2 ? Both x'Ay and y'Ax can be negative or positive. To prove that x'Ay is an inner product, we should prove the triangular inequality.

Comment: Actually, I want to prove that f(x) is a vector norm; therefore, I need to prove the triangular inequality.

Comment: It follows from properties of inner product. After you establish cauchy-schwartz you have your result